# Pull latest bitbucket commit via Nodejs

Tags: node.js, automation, bitbucket

I would like to make a code that pulls the source code of my latest commit in bitbucket and doing it using Nodejs.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install bitbucket:<bitbucketname>/<bitbucketrepo>[#<commit-ish>]`

From npm [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> Install the package at https://bitbucket.org/bitbucketname/bitbucketrepo by attempting to clone it using git

Comment: Just did, thanks. Now I would like to know how to execute command lines on the Node JS in order to run the pull from bitbucket command

Comment: @Natezz I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. You would typically not execute npm commands at runtime. Just run the above command in a terminal and your package will be installed/updated.

Comment: I'm sorry but im kinda new at this. if my project name is X and my repo is Y, what do I need to execute in order to get the latest commit ? @rckrd

Comment: Run this in a terminal/command prompt: `npm install bitbucket:X/Y` @Natezz

Comment: That's what it leads to :    pm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

Comment: Your repo is private, you need to create ssh keys on your machine and add it to your repo. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/add-an-ssh-key-to-an-account-302811853.html